# How to perform operation on columns using column indexes (and not names) of a data frame using dplyr?

Tags: r, sorting, dplyr

I'm trying to make more extensive use of dplyr and have a question regarding the (row-wise) operations using column indexes instead of column names. In my workflow, I have data tables in which the first column will be a char() identifier and the last column also a char() data type. All the columns between the first and last contains numeric values that will be used for operations - in this example: sort by abundance and only keep the 5 more abundant rows.

Here is an example using classic R:

```
example_file = "~/path/my/data/example_table.tsv"
df = data.frame(fread(example_file, header=TRUE), check.names=FALSE)
df$sum = rowSums(df[,2:(ncol(df)-1)])
df = df[order(-df$sum),]
df = df[1:5,]
```

Here is the `dput` output of my df:

```
df <- structure(list(feature = 1111:1117, A = c(2L, 1L, 0L, 1L, 11L, 
1L, 0L), B = c(1L, 0L, 1L, 2L, 1L, 1L, 10L), C = c(0L, 1L, 2L, 
0L, 2L, 2L, 1L), D = c(1L, 3L, 3L, 3L, 1L, 3L, 3L), E = c(4L, 
4L, 3L, 4L, 4L, 3L, 4L), F = c(1L, 0L, 0L, 1L, 1L, 1L, 2L), G = c(1L, 
2L, 2L, 2L, 21L, 4L, 2L), H = c(6L, 7L, 4L, 7L, 7L, 7L, 1L), 
    taxonomy = c("Eukaryota;Centrohelida;H15-6", "Eukaryota;Excavata;Discoba;Discicristata;Euglenozoa;Diplonemea;Rhynchopus", 
    "undef", "Eukaryota;Excavata;Discoba;Discicristata;Euglenozoa;Euglenida;Heteronematina", 
    "Eukaryota;Excavata;Discoba;Discicristata;Euglenozoa;Euglenida;Heteronematina", 
    "Eukaryota;Excavata;Discoba;Discicristata;Euglenozoa;", "Eukaryota;SAR;Alveolata;Ciliophora;Intramacronucleata"
    )), class = "data.frame", row.names = c(NA, -7L))
```

My question is very simple: how does one implements the above code using the dplyr paradigm? I was intuitively looking for a way to manipulate the df with column indexes - like I did in the above code chunk - but didn't find any satisfying answers.

Any guidance would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

One way to do this would to be as follows:

```
library(tidyverse)

df %>% 
  group_by(feature, taxonomy) %>% 
  nest() %>% 
  mutate(sumz = map(data, rowSums)) %>%
  unnest(c(data, sumz)) %>% 
  arrange(-sumz) %>% 
  slice(1:5)
```

Here I `nest` feature and taxonomy which creates basically a vector of values. I then use the `mutate` function to add a new column called sumz (rather than sum, just so I don't mess with a function name). I map the `rowSums` function across the nested data. I then unnest to return a data frame and use `arrange` and `slice` similar to what you did above. If you were interested in the top 5 unit, you could just use the `top_n` function to select those.

As far as your question about numeric references, you can use those in dplyr esque syntax. You can also use the `****_if` functions like `group_by_if(is.character)` etc to apply the function based on a logical that you provide.